# Documentation - a recreation of another "Stack Overflow" site?

Tags: discussion, documentation

We have tons of excellent examples in Stack Overflow, and here in Documentation beta we are recreating another site with examples. It would have been a good idea if questions are linked for individual topics, but rather individual examples are to be created.

Question 1:

> Is there any option to link with questions in a particular tag with a
>   topic (it would have been great)? Otherwise it will be just like copying contents from Stack Overflow
>   and pasting in Documentation

Question 2:

> How to search for a topic in Documentation, as there is no ordering
>   on concepts based on its complexity?

Below is an example where you can find SQL intro is seen between other topics, rather an order for that being the basic one -

[image]

Comment: Did you read the tour, and announcements on how Documentation is different from Q&A? Sure, there are plenty of questions that are *about* topics, but they're very seldom canonical or general enough in nature (for obvious reasons). Documentation doesn't require a question.

Comment: @J.Steen , yes i have read the descriptions but we have some good canonical answers in SO , i hope you too would agree..what about those answer posts ?

Comment: They are answers to specific questions. Documentation is a way to create code examples and descriptive text without having a (usually poorly written) question to start it off.

Comment: i totally agree with you , but we have examples for beginners too in SO , why code again with examples if an option is available to mark availability of such answers from SO

Comment: While both sites could, in theory, contain the same information I totally prefer Documentation due to the clean, uncluttered experience you get. No comments asking for "y u no code", no horrible images of exceptions, no short and uncommented answers... just the pure facts of a topic. =)

Comment: for example in sql server documentation i have an example of what a database is , which might not be available in SO , but there are other canonical posts which should be made available under some topics , cos those posts are textbooks for some of the concepts in pgmming

Comment: Documentation and Q&A are ultimately going to contain a lot of the same information, that's a given. It's not a sign Documentation is going to be useless.

Comment: @Pekka웃 , documentation should be done but here we are recreating all the examples and missing out canonical posts in SO

Comment: What do you mean by "missing out" exactly? SO Q&A will continue to exist, that is guaranteed. But a lot of canonical content will be moved, or copied over, to Documentation. I find it hard to see a problem in that

Comment: @Pekka웃 but how can we move the same ? is there any option currently rather copying and pasting as topics ?

Comment: Nope - but copying & pasting should be fine. My currently only contribution there is copied&pasted, too (and edited a little bit).

Comment: @Pekka웃 we don't tolerate exact duplicate answers on the main site, so why is it okay to dupe them in the docs? Also, what about cc-by-sa, attribution required? Is it okay when I copy your stuff over to docs without attribution? What about the rep I'll gain for your work?

Comment: @Gordon I'm talking exclusively about copying *your own* content, should have made that clearer. In many cases (e.g. for self-answered "how-to" questions that fit much better in Documentation now) that is going to be a good thing to do. Copying *other people's* content is not ok, although I guess it is legal if done with attribution.

Comment: @Pekka웃 that is not what is happening right now though. Also, does that imply that self-answering is no longer welcome?

Comment: @Gordon that's bad then :( Re whether self-answering is still welcome, I don't know! But I assume so.

Comment: @Pekka웃: copying & pasting is not fine. Instead of copy example provide a link to existing example on SO or on any other site. Only if you can make an example better, add it to the topic. Use links instead of plagiate.

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim re-using your own content is hardly plagiarism. Having a documentation that is made up of links to SO answers doesn't make any sense at all - content has to be edited to fit the new form, and be subject to whatever quality control processes Documentation will come up with. `Only if you can make an example better, add it to the topic.`  that goes without saying.

Comment: @utility: You should submit 2 separate suggestions: 1.Provide way to link SO questions and 2. Provide editing tool to move examples within a topic. For the first question I think the normal link button in editor is sufficient, regardless you refer to SO answer or any external topic.

Comment: @Pekka웃: IMHO, content do NOT need to be edited to fit the new form, if it's exist in any place on internet in a form, that it's good enough for reader. For topics, where no extra value can be added, collection of links will be sufficient.  Duplication is not good in a code, not good in SO answers, it is not good between normal SO and Docs.SO

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim is that ok to ask separate question now ? then what to do with this post ?

Comment: @utility: Most of the discussion is related to the first question, so leave it here. Move question 2 to a separate question, and put here reference that you migrated q2 to a separate question.

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim thats a good idea..thank you :)