# 10 reputation for topic editing is too high

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, reputation, documentation

On Q & A Stack Overflow, Suggested Edits are a prime source of rep farming; a simple or trivial edit that requires little knowledge of the question content earns users under 2k reputation two rep for each approved edit.

In a similar style, suggesting '*topic improvements*' (the docs terminology for suggesting an edit) earns the editor reputation. Specifically, 10 reputation for each upvote on any topic they've edited.

This creates an investment style reputation gain from potentially trivial edits.

If I go through right now and edit every topic, there's a good chance I could have a Jon Skeet (*rep cap everyday*) style reputation gain.

[image]

Can we either improve the requirements on incoming edits or decrease the rep gain for example upvotes?

Comment: Fully agree with you. The balancing is "a bit" off :/

Comment: Fully agreed, It'll attract rep farmers like hell.

Comment: or remove the rep gain.. Let documentation be written by people who are genuinely interesting in creating good documentation. Not by people who want to earn rep

Comment: Wait, if i'm editing someone else's example, i'll start getting their rep???? This is not good at all

Comment: @AlonEitan it's not _someone else's_ example, there's not an author. This is a collaborative style edit structure where we're all working together. Kinda like Community Wiki

Comment: @Quill But I still getting rep for "something" I did there, so if i'll edit any example i'll (theoretically) immediately start "enjoy" free rep? I'm referring to what the OP wrote: _ff I go through right now and edit every topic, there's a good chance I could have a Jon Skeet (rep cap everyday) style reputation gain._

Comment: @AlonEitan yes, that is exactly the problem (btw, I am the OP)

Comment: @TimCastelijns well, then we probably need a way to report approvers of low quality content. Perhaps you could reduce the review limit for the bad approvers so that we get less of that.

Comment: Like Undo says on Tim's answer, Gamification is SO's carrot-and-stick. If we want the users to keep contributing, providing rewards is a great way to get them to do so

Comment: I've actually pointed this out in Docs Beta before during *private beta* - http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/1206/easier-to-earn-reputation-with-documentation?noredirect=1 (not available now, since private ended)

Comment: I'm going to add the same comment I added in chat: Currently I feel really proud, not about my rep, but about the fact that if one looks at my answers they are positive scores with a good number of accepted. So the +10 for all edits seems to trivialize answerers on the main site

Comment: @luweiqi http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/1206/easier-to-earn-reputation-with-documentation?noredirect=1

Comment: @Knu Yup, that is it

Comment: -1 : For overtaking The Skeet I need this feature ....

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing a graph of total reputation across all users on SO to see if there's a sharp increase in the line today - is that sort of data public on [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/)?

Comment: @JamesThorpe SEDE data is a week old

Comment: @Quill Ok - next week then :)  Question still stands though - is overall total rep across the site grouped by day accessible/possible.  I've not used it nearly enough to know...

Comment: @JamesThorpe you could use the API, I guess

Comment: This is the [Oprah Winfrey of reputation](https://cdn.meme.am/instances/400x/53073449.jpg)

Comment: Should the `Feature Request` and/or `Support` tags be added to this post?  I think this is far more too important to be _only_ `discussion`

Comment: @RGA feature-request, sure. Support, no. _A request for assistance with one of the site's features_ does not apply in the slighest

Comment: @Quill agreed.  I meant it more as a desperate cry for help from the mods and devs :P

Comment: Kind of related: [Should rep gains be turned off for Documentation's seeding period?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328500/should-rep-gains-be-turned-off-for-documentations-seeding-period)

Comment: It is a true gold mine now.

Answer (score 76):

> Can we either improve the requirements on incoming edits or decrease the rep gain for example upvotes?

or remove the rep gain altogether..

Let documentation be written by people who are genuinely interesting in creating good documentation. Not by people who want to earn rep.

---

As an argument against "if people are not given rep they won't contribute", let me introduce you to [SOCVFinder](https://stackapps.com/questions/6910/socvfinder-providing-enjoyable-reviewing-live-duplicate-notifications-and-cher), a chat room where people are given a way to spend their close votes more effectively.

Over the past 2-3 months  **a handful of people** have closed **4254** questions. They invest time and effort, yet they are not rewarded. They do it because they think it matters.

Comment: Though, it goes through a review queue, so it won't be too much problematic. If rep farmers actually improve docs… then everyone wins. But I agree, rep gain could be lower…

Comment: I'm going to disagree with this. Reputation is, as we've seen, an awesome motivator. It has its downsides, but just removing it altogether is a good way to ensure you'll have a ghosttown on your hands. It could be adjusted, but not removed.

Comment: @Undo Gaining reputation for a documentation example used in an answer is totally fine but not for an upvote, that's way to inflationary.

Comment: @reVerse well, that's the classical problem of SO answers which are just RTFM. My highest reputation answer is typical RTFM for example. … But I don't think we can do very much against this except removing all motivation [I also fear Undo's ghosttown scenario].

Comment: @Undo reputation is an awesome motivator because it has so much value. If you give it away too easily, it loses that value

Comment: @TimCastelijns I'm not saying that it couldn't or shouldn't be adjusted - I agree with you that Docs rep is a little too easy to come by right now. (If *I* can get it it's probably too easy to get)

Comment: I agree with both Tim-Castelijns and @Undo. Perhaps one solution would be to make Documentation a new Stackexchange site with its own reputation rankings

Comment: @bwoebi That may be true but the issue with the documentation is that everyone who contributed to the example get the reputation. So one upvote may lead to a rep gain of 200 distributed over 20 user.

Comment: @reVerse oh, didn't realize that. Perhaps you should get rep proportional to contribution … but that can be gamed too I think (by reordering things etc.) So … don't know :-/

Comment: @user2314737 That would be the best, "documentation.stackoverflow.com". Due to technical complexity, probably not feasible in the short term though.

Comment: @Undo I've commented in [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328444/documenting-the-problems-with-documentation#328444) that denying uses from their credit is not right, but don't you think that getting rep. on any edit is being a little too generous reputation-wise?

Comment: @AlonEitan Not really. They're suggestions at this point, and require people to review them, so let's treat them like suggested edits. I agree that +10 might be a little strong, though.

Comment: Re edit: The bar to closing questions is also much, much lower than writing good documentation...

Comment: @bwoebi that is very true. But the idea counts

Comment: @Undo  You should know full well that the suggested edit review system is trash.  Even spam and vandalism regularly get approved.  It's almost impossible to write a suggested edit that *doesn't* get approved, even if you're *trying* to get it denied.  It won't do squat to stop people just trying to earn tons of rep while spending as little time and effort as possible.  If the suggested edit review system was actually given enough attention to stop that from happening, then that argument would have merit.

Comment: Even a reduction from 10 rep to 2 would be a huge improvement to fighting rep farming.

Comment: @Undo I'm happy that you agree that +10 might be a little strong, because up until now the rep. system was brilliantly balanced (This, with the badges and the privileges were what made SO the success it is today IMO), and I'm worried that it will have unwanted results with too much uses with high rep and low **real** contribution. So I hope some adjustments will be added to make the rep balanced again

Comment: On the bright side of high rep gain resides a pool of more close voters (frustrated that *any* documentation wasn't read). That said, I'd make it a separate site.

Comment: @Undo: [This user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4490559/intboolstring?tab=reputation) got ___1900___ rep today. If the rep was reduced to 2 per vote, that would've been _380_ in _one_ day. That's still a _massive_ amount.
Frankly, the rep gain should be reworked. It's too easy to get an edit in and farm rep from that. Look up some topics with a lot of visitors, make a couple of minor edits, and boom, [trusted user](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) in a week!

Comment: @Cerbrus That's because (1) the rep cap is broken right now, and (2) intboolstring put in many hours during the private beta writing documentation. He didn't just show up this morning and FGITW a few things.

Comment: I can appreciate the effort put in there. But in the couple of hours documentation has been online, he's gotten enough votes to reach the rep cap for more than a week. Get enough edits in, and you're set for a guaranteed daily +200 rep.

Comment: There might be seperate docs rep or docs badges(gold etc.) for those who want a motivator but adding docs rep into SO rep is just _weird_.

Comment: Frankly I'm horrified at a personal +160 (so far) just for making a small edit to a Hello World example back in the early days of the private beta.  I'm torn between wishing I'd done more in case something isn't changed/fixed with this and thinking it's not a good situation.

Comment: @Servy actually the only way you get rejected is if you introduced a critical but minor edit to the code that the author missed... that's the only sure way.

Comment: For those who are not rep-farming and have some knowledge to contribute (and other things to do) reducing the rep gain will mean we can't get the privileges we need to do contribute.

Comment: @adjpayot I don't understand. You don't need privileges to contribute knowledge

Comment: @TimCastelijns Contributing not just meaning writing answers, editing, voting, etc.. TBH I'm not sure how everything works, especially in the documentation, I just wanted to say that not everyone is desperately trying to get reps through trivial edits and that reducing it might trivialise some of the work people do. Even if you don't do it for the rep, since the system exists its the way your contribution is valued.

Comment: @adjpayot ah. Well, it's a privilege for a reason. You're not supposed to have the privilege without having worked to deserve it. Even people who have 40 years experience programming but are new to SO have to earn their privileges here. If everyone could easily unlock the privileges, they would not be privileges anymore

Comment: @Tim _If everyone could easily unlock the privileges, they would not be privileges anymore_ I agree, seems to be the epitome of our discussions.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yes. It's a privilege for a reason. And someone editing the documentation constructively should probably get somewhere eventually, which is not what this answer is suggesting.

Comment: @Undo http://en.cppreference.com/w/ doesn't have rep, but it's still an amazing resource, one that SO Docs will have a hard time matching no matter how many rep-seekers are posting copy-pasteable examples.

Comment: @Undo: "intboolstring put in many hours during the private beta writing documentation" This is excellent, and I don't wish to demonize this user at all. Disregarding the person, then, and just looking at the system, I have a hard time seeing how [changing a half-dozen variable names](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/4425) should earn someone [nearly 1k rep](http://i.stack.imgur.com/58wzE.png). That's _100 upvotes_. That's the equivalent of _many_ well-recieved answers: a _lot_ of work in the pre-Doc system.

Comment: @JoshCaswell No one should be getting 1k+ rep from one edit in one day, and there's probably a better way to run reputation (less for smaller edits; but it's frustratingly hard to measure). I do want to be careful of throwing away reputation earned by hard-working folks put in during the beta period. That's a small concern and I don't want to die on that hill; it won't really matter in two months anyway.

Comment: "I do want to be careful of throwing away reputation earned by hard-working folks put in during the beta period" Fair point; recognition and reward for getting the whole thing started is important. @Undo

Answer (score 69):

## The Hyperinflation of Reputation caused by Documentation <sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup>#alliteration</sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub>

As Tim addressed, I believe the rep gains should be removed all together, or at least seperated from the main SO reputation.  Beyond the issues of reputation no longer truly representing the "trust placed in you by the community," allowing these ***massive rep gains for trivial changes*** will soon create an influx of **low-rep users with high-rep privileges**.

Users with little experience on SO, knowledge of the topics, and minimal investment in the *quality* of the site can (even unintentionally) farm massive amounts of reputation, giving them privileges for moderation that **do not correctly represent the "trust" given to them by the community**.  Given that this is a fundamental pillar of the SO reputation model, documentation seems to be blowing a hole in the entire system.

Perhaps, as a way of retaining incentive but removing the destruction of all we hold dear, many more badges could be added to reward active participants in Documentation (badges that can be earned multiple times to encourage continued use) without scewing the current privilege system.   Review queues, for example, do not reward any reputation, yet the Badge earning incentives are sufficient to keep the machine oiled and churning out quality content.

Comment: *low-rep users with high-rep privileges* this is a contradiction ;-)

Comment: @TimCastelijns I feel like the intentional contradiction is the only way to describe it!  Honestly, I'm terrified of the implications for SO if this is allowed to continue

Comment: I totally agree. There is so much crap on the site, being a high rep user will have no correlation with programming competency, if that's the case, I won't be participating anymore. It's hard work getting rep from writing good questions and answers. It's bad enough people can make heaps from suggested edits, now users won't have to compile a program at all.

Comment: @Yvette exactly.  Reputation was something I was proud of, regardless of how meager it was, and it felt like a good representation of knowledge on a topic.  Even though unknowledgeable people could farm rep, the effort required felt like a significant enough barrier, but now there is nothing.  Even with max-daily rep being restored, this current distribution is broken

Comment: No reason someone should be given elevated privileges for copy and pasting something from an existing documentation. If this is truly supposed to be a wiki, remove all reputation. At a minimum separate it from SO. Seems like it was a blind decision.

Comment: @CubeJockey I really enjoyed participating in SO because I felt like I was earning something from the work and time I put in.  Now, it all just feels cheap.  It's like a hyperinflation of rep.  I feel completely discouraged from participating now

Comment: @CubeJockey things lose value when anyone can easily obtain them.

Comment: @Braiam note the title added to my answer :P

Comment: I was just saying it without flowery (or with more flowery?).

Comment: but badges can't be used for bounties

Answer (score 15):

Another take on this would be to award reputation only once per accepted edit. For example:

- guy/gal edits content
- content gets approved
- 2-10 rep gained
- stop

This is similar to how edits on posts are made. This also removes the need for the whole voting system on Documentation (which looks awkward to me).

Comment: How about a cap on doc rep, like 500 max, lifetime. Not per post, but total max per user. That could at least keep it on this site, without causing people to flee.

Comment: @Drew I'm definitely in favour of adding a maximum cap per account on this sort of reputation, independently from the awarding system. Just like the aforementioned edits on posts already does (2'000 per account IIRC).

Comment: I want to suggest more specific: 10 rep.for approved new topic/example, 2 rep for approved edit.

Answer (score 0):

Having observed some examples, noticed that *not* any edit allows the editor to gain the rep from upvotes. You should do something more than just improving indentation of the code or linking some words to a site, otherwise you're not getting the rep from the consequent upvotes *at all*. 
However, adding a sentence and editing code already does give the rep for consequent upvotes.

I do agree though, that the current system for rewarding the editors is still not great.

The threshold for rewarding should be lifted (recently seen an edit which has added 30 chars, and the editor was still gaining +10 for every upvote).

I propose to change the rewarding rules as follows:

- An edit which doesn't exceed 200 chars - each next upvotes doesn't reward the editor.
- An edit added 200 to 500 chars - each next upvote gives **5** rep.
- An edit which added more than 500 chars - each next upvote gives **10** rep.

Comment: Even so, the definition of a "substantial" edit needs to be changed to justify the rep gains

Comment: 30 chars of comment may be trivial and not worth anything.  30 chars of core code could make all the difference between a mediocre example and a great example.  It's a tough line to draw.

Comment: @James Makes sense, the edit I was referencing added a *comment* to the *code*.

Comment: It will just be gamed. Rules change, they game those. How about this following link, where an edit of 30 characters would be stellar. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/855/table-deletion/2899/basic-delete#t=201607211855585421285)

Comment: @Drew oh, can't disagree with you on this one. Yes, probably my proposal has flaws.

Comment: Also it seems like almost every change is getting accepted; there's not a lot of critical reviewing going on, which is also part of the problem. Doesn't matter what kind of limits are imposed, if nobody's paying attention to the edits...