# Set reputation cap per example for Documentation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

I agree that Documentation currently awards too much reputation as seen from [10 reputation for topic editing is too high](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328491/10-reputation-for-topic-editing-is-too-high) and [Should rep gains be turned off for Documentation's seeding period?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328500/should-rep-gains-be-turned-off-for-documentations-seeding-period).

By contributing to a wide variety of examples in Documentation, it would be quite easy to get reputation when an answer citing the example is upvoted.

However, would it be possible to set a reputation cap by example, maybe +50 per example, rather than a total cap of 200 currently.