# How to Flag Stack Overflow Documentation for deletion?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

Today while I was looking for some useful Solr document in StackOverflow documentation, I found a topic (Lucene Query Syntax) containing basic examples clearly explained in the [Solr documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax), the [Lucene documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html) and a gazillion of other sources. When I looked for an option to flag this topic for deletion or at least as not useful, I couldn't find it. I think that existing documentation shouldn't be imported in S.O. as it just adds garbage to filter during user search.

While I am sure that the authors meant well and so I don't want to downvote the doc, I am wondering:

Is there a way to flag such documentation when we find it?

If the answer to the question above is "no" as I think, shouldn't we allow the community to flag documents that have been imported, copied or that have a clear counterpart on many sources included the product documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can flag documentation. Look for the flag icon on the top right of each topic:

[image]

But I'm not sure that a topic being well covered elsewhere is a good reason to remove something... Sure if it's a direct copy paste, then it should be flagged for removal, but for the people who look to Stack Overflow first for their docs having some redundant info can be a good thing.

Think of it as a one stop shop. Hopefully, one day, we'll have a nice curated heap of documentation all at the same address.

Comment: Keep in mind these aren't [real flags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329025/6083675), they are actually just improvement requests.

Comment: If you can see it as a 12k user, why can't I see it? Do I need a bronze badge on the tag or something?