# Should the editor of a flagged (link-only) answer get the reputation from upvotes?

Tags: discussion

A while ago I stumbled upon [this link-only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1208272/3410196) and flagged it so, however, because it was the accepted answer and had a lot of upvotes I got the following response on my flag (which is understandable):

> helpful - I understand why you're flagging this, but I'm not deleting an accepted answer with 154 upvotes that isn't dead.

However, today I stumbled again on the answer and a relatively new user [edited it into a pretty good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1208272/3). Since may when I flagged the question, the answer has received 49 more upvotes, so it's a popular answer, but isn't it a shame that this user who turned the original answer (link-only so pretty much garbage) into a **good** answer won't get any reputation for it? For me he deserves the rep way more than the author of the original answer?

Perhaps when a (popular) answer has been flagged a few times, someone who edits should 'own' the answer from then on? Of course it's hard to determine what exactly is a *good* edit, but maybe someone has a better suggestion?

Comment: I should point out that such post-saving edits by someone else tend to be fairly rare. Almost all edits that have completely converted link-based answers into more detailed ones are done by the author in response to comments.

Comment: @BradLarson Perhaps it can be done manually instead of automatically then? I just don't think is fair that that user who did the work doesn't get anything, and the guy who posted a link gets a few thousand rep.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck the user who did all the work knew what they were doing, and as I put in an answer, they could have posted an answer of their own.

Comment: @Renan Which 80% of the visitors wouldn't see because they follow the link of a highly upvoted answer straight away. I doubt his answer would ever get attention, it was the best thing he could do to edit it imo (making SO better).

Answer (score 5):

They'll get two points for the editing if they don't have the [immediate editing privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

Other than that, I don't think the proposal would be a good idea. People with reputation point over 2,000 could do minor edits to popular answers, improving nothing while gaming the system for undeserved reputation.

I think a more appropriate course of action, if the editor wants to gain reputation from their efforts, is to pick a link from a link-only answer (LOA) and write a new, better answer based on that. Going further, I think I'd be motivated to give them a bounty in cases where they bring content into Stack Overflow rather than relying on external links.

Comment: *'when a (popular) answer has been flagged a few times'*, so not just any answer.

Comment: *People with reputation over 2,000 could do minor edits to popular answers* - why, [whatever would give you that indication](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329528/remove-or-overhaul-reputation-in-documentation)?