# Fix Documentation change approval requirements

Tags: discussion, documentation

Ignoring all the other issues with Documentation being addressed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328491/6408573), and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328519/6408573), and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328444/6408573), and everywhere else on meta right now, there is a **HUGE** problem with the approval process for changes.  Since there is not rep, tag, or badge requirements to approve a change, and only two approvals are needed to push the change through, there has been an incredible amount of crap flowing through Documentation.  I've seen multiple instances where examples or changes are approved where the information contained is just flat-out ***wrong***.

For example, in the Excel-vba documentation, the following addition was approved to a "Best Practices" Topic:

> In the VBA Editor window, from the Tools menu select "Options". Then
>   in the "Editor" tab, make sure that "Require Variable Declaration" is
>   checked. Selecting this option will automatically put Option Explicit
>   at the top of every VBA module.
>
> This will require the user to declare every variable with a specific
>   type. If this option is not used, all undeclared variables default to
>   type Variant. This often leads to attempts to mix or compare
>   information of different types, generating error messages that are
>   difficult to understand ("why isn't VBA letting me do what I want it
>   to do?!").

Not only is this a pretty terribly written explanation, the information is just *completely inadequate, bordering inaccurate*, yet the change was approved.  One quick google of "Option Explicit" will show you that this explanation is **completely innaccurate**. I went ahead and editted the post to correct the information, but clearly the approval process needs to be fixed.

Comment: I'm not clear on how reputation is being assigned to people contributing to the documentation but wouldn't a completely erroneous but approved edit generate reputation for its author??

Comment: @Louis reputation is gained for all those who have made "substantial" changes.  The point is more that the approval process is too lax, particularly given that there seems to be no required knowledge of a language

Comment: "*here has been an incredible amount of crap flowing through Documentation*" Fully agreed! I personally feel quiet frustrated, not being able to reject/comment/correct fast enough on inaccurate, ambiguous or sometimes even plain wrong posts, while lowlow-rep user (in the specific tag) continue approving the crap. *sigh*

Comment: In the related vba tag, I just ran across an example that had nothing to do with the topic, was incorrect, belonged in another ***tag***, and linked to an MSDN page ***for a different language***.  This edit was approved by a user who has never posted ***anything*** in a tag even remotely related to the vba tag.  AFAIK [it's still sitting there waiting for a second deletion approval](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/62435).  Not exactly putting the best foot forward with the public content.  This needs to be fixed.  Soon.