# Get rid of rep on docs

Tags: discussion, documentation

I am having a hard time with the amount of crap examples I have run into on docs.  The majority of it is low rep folks who seem to be gaming the system.  I propose and I know this might cause some people to back off of contributing is to actually remove rep all together on docs.  The backing off may actually be the best thing ever to happen to docs currently.

Yes this means less people will contribute to docs, but at the same time this is what we need right now.  The point of documentation, even outside of SO, is that it should be clear, concise, and very much correct.  The examples need to relate to the topic at hand and there actually should be less content but much better content.

Right now, its a free for all and people are taking advantage of that.  It's a burden on myself and anyone else who is looking at and reviewing all of this stuff.  The folks who want to document and do it correctly do not care about rep, they care that people use an api correctly, they take special care that examples are much clearer than what they currently are.

**Please consider removing rep on docs once and for all.**

Comment: surely this is a duplicate of something

Comment: There might be less people contributing, but the ones doing it, will do it for the right reasons.

Comment: @ryanyuyu - if it's a duplicate you can mark it as such and link to appropriate question on meta.

Comment: @MariaDeleva - precisely - this is the intent!

Comment: Possible dupes: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329940/can-we-please-introduce-more-reputation-limits-for-examples-on-documentation - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328703/addressing-documentation-repgateapocalypse - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329191/should-1-rep-users-be-allowed-to-write-documentation - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328607/why-is-documentation-reputation-counted-as-the-main-reputation - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328593/fix-documentation-change-approval-requirements

Comment: @TylerH - None of those are for completely removing rep.

Comment: Also related: [Remove or Overhaul Reputation in Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329528/remove-or-overhaul-reputation-in-documentation) (which asks for removal of reputation, but is willing to compromise with an overhaul)

Comment: This proposal is not constructive. Stack Overflow and every part of the Stack Exchange network revolves around rep; it's what drives user activity and user retention here. They are not going to get rid of it.

Comment: Then it could just be separated from SO. It would still be better than it is now.

Comment: @MariaDeleva [A split of Docs reputation is currently not being pursued](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328693/4320665)

Comment: @TylerH - To that I say bahhh, then I should get rep for all the Job posting bugs and usage and reports.  That too is integrated with SO.

Comment: @ryanyuyu that doesn't mean it shouldn't be.

Comment: @JonH Those are meta contributions for which rep is not attributed.