# Why is documentation reputation counted as the main reputation?

Tags: discussion, documentation

**TL;DR**

> or remove the rep gain.. Let documentation be written by people who
> are genuinely interesting in creating good documentation. Not by
> people who want to earn rep – [Tim Castelijns](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328491/10-reputation-for-topic-editing-is-too-high#comment369370_328491)

I would love to contribute to documentation, but honestly, I don't want that free reputation, I've contributed already which is awaiting review but honestly, I am not looking for reputation.

---

Edit: I didn't knew that I can get reputation by adding/editing docs, I did because I wanted to contribute. I realized after this user posted a message in the chat room

> Documentation at the moment = rep gold mine lmao - [explv](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31835173#31835173)

Chat message below that is mine, where I meant that we **shouldn't**

---

To be honest, I was surprised to see that users creating documentation topics, examples etc are awarded reputation points which is absolutely wrong.

Now am not saying that they don't deserve any reputation points for the hard work they put to build the documentation topics/content but this is not fair to other users who earned the reputation points by answering on questions.

Most of the users are simply picking up basic snippets from MDN, W3C (am sharing these resources as am a web dev, this might be different for different languages) and hence don't deserve the free reputation. It is easy to farm the reputation like this.

---

**Community Wiki? Start providing points to those users too than**

Also, this reminds me of our community answers, where people contribute together without earning a single rep, only to make those answers useful.

---

Not sure what others think, it might be that people are in the favor of current system but tbh, am not happy. For me, am a self taught developer, and I know what it takes to earn this reputation, by answering the questions in the best way I can, and not the easily farmed one by sharing basic HTML and CSS tags and properties in the documentation. Would love to know what community thinks about this.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328491/10-reputation-for-topic-editing-is-too-high

Comment: @Floern Related but yea, not a dupe, want to get this reputation counted as a separate thing rather than adding it to the existing main profile

Comment: Docs is now a part of SO. Why distinguish by an answer that helps someone, and documentation that answers/helps someone? If someone up votes that documentation as helpful, why shouldn't a person get SO rep?

Comment: @PetahChristian So picking up snippets from MDN and W3C and putting it over here deserves reputation?

Comment: It was also [discussed here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328444/documenting-the-problems-with-documentation#328444) and why exactly it's not fair to other users who earned the reputation points by answering on questions? If you wrote good example, it shouldn't be less important from any other answer posted on SO. You can always copy other recourses when answering on SO, and the community decide it it's worth upvoting/downvoting

Comment: @AlonEitan Answer might require research or a new solution all in general which might not be documented and would take lot of efforts by the OP to write the answer, docs are something which is already available everywhere, collecting that info and putting it on Stackoverflow and earning reputation is no where near to efforts taken by OP to write answers,

Comment: @Mr.Alien But don't you think that great examples will require the same effort as answering on SO - To be able to think of the topic without having uses asking you questions about,  providing an original and simple to understand code, writing a clear description, etc..

Comment: @AlonEitan I am not saying that don't award the users, count this reputation as a separate thing all together, like, documentation profile + rep should be separate from main, contribute for the sake of contributing, who are really interested. All we will have later is editors to gain rep for mere edits, vamps everywhere...

Comment: @Mr.Alien I also agree that editors should not get any credit on edits in the Documentation, but I still think that the original author of any great example should rewarded as if they posted a great answer on SO, because behind every upvoter there's a user that learned something, that without that example they might otherwise ask a question about that topic on SO

Comment: Not sure why this is even being voted for a duplicate, as that user is trying to lower down the reputation per action on docs whereas am trying to get rid of it.

Comment: Actually, it's not even consistent. I hit the 200-rep cap yesterday for the first time, yet didn't get the Mortarboard badge.

Comment: FWIW @Mr.Alien If you see any content copied from MDN or similar sites, flag it as copied content and it will be deleted (it's explicitly disallowed) and the associated rep will be revoked too.

Comment: @TylerH hardly matters, not feeling like contributing anymore unless they revert their new ways of throwing reputation. This was supposed tobe one of the addition in programmers profile which showed his experience, now reputation has no meaning left.

Comment: Documentation reputation is still a thing, so this is not no longer reproducible.

Answer (score 54):

Just a suggestion here to StackExchange team, if we stick to the current way, I am sure that users will start losing interest soon. Lowering the reputation gained by editing docs won't help either.

We should instead consider Documentation as an all together separate section just like we had meta previously where people used to gain reputation but was counted as a separate profile.

This will not only help controlling the reputation flow, but it will also show the users contribution very specifically for the documentation.

---

Am hardly contributing since last one and a half year because of the quality of questions we get, and now this demotivates me further to contribute. As, we are making everything a rep game, which I don't think is cool atleast for the documentation which you get it anyways on the respective product website / github repo, or language docs. I loved and supported the docs idea because I wanted to get all info at one place, kinda one stop shop, but no rep stuff here. See if we can change this and than I would love to contribute to the docs.

Keeping my couple of documentation edits as is, won't be writing more cuz I don't want free rep.

Peace \m/

Answer (score 28):

Thinking about this issue has been kinda hard for me, since SO Docs has been the first time I've really felt like I've really been able to contribute to the community without facing such stiff competition as I often do when trying to answer questions, but I'm starting to think that separating out documentation rep is probably a good idea.

I want people to be able to see how much work I've put into docs, but I probably don't deserve this:

[image]

**Explanation:** My first docs contribution was on April 5. During the beta period I put a lot of work into fleshing out the CSS topic, and have done cosmetic and proof-reading-type editing in many other topics. Since documentation going public, I've seen a *huge spike* in reputation flow, to the point where I'm maxing out at 200 rep a day *before I even wake up in the morning,* and since it's gone public I basically haven't even made any more contributions because I don't like fighting with other people to get my edits reviewed.

Granted, reputation flow may start to flatten out as people get over the *newness* of the docs, but this still seems indicative that Q&A rep and Docs rep are just two entirely different beasts.

Comment: I'm curious: why do you feel like the competition is less stiff for documentation than for answering questions? I see the exact opposite. There are *tons* of people participating in docs, and in a much more concentrated area (there are zillions of questions, whereas there are only a manageable number of docs topics right now).

Comment: @CodyGray I felt that way while Docs was in beta. Now I very much agree with you: Given the constraints you mention and the collision-prone edit-and-review system, Docs is *much* more competitive than Q&A now. This is actually one reason I've been conflicted about docs rep at times. I feel like people who were in the beta had a much bigger chance to run into the scenario outlined in my answer, whereas people contributing now are going to have to work much harder to get the kind of crazy rep gains I'm seeing.

Comment: My bet is that right now everyone who has done an edit to an example, will gain +5 for each upvote after the edit has been accepted. The system might be a just a little bit broken.

Answer (score -11):

I would rather limit the maximum amount of gained rep than remove it altogether. This way it would be similar to the rep gained by aproved edits.

If the rep from docs is limited to, say 500 rep, this would probably motivate many low-rep users and not impact too much on the high-rep users.

Comment: That's still to much reputation gain. If anything it should be part of the 200 reputation a day you can get from upvotes. The entire problem with this is that people aren't editing the documentation to make it better, rather editing popular ones just enough (with unneeded or somewhat off-topic info). Eventually the pages will be boated with unimportant information just so the users can get a share of the reputation gain.