# Let documentation having its own meta site

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, meta, documentation

Well, the documentation beta had gone out in the wild today, and MSO is flooded with atypical questions.

Wouldn't it be more useful instead of having all of these [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation) related tags, to give the whole thing its own meta site?

Just a bit of annoyed today.

Comment: The goal here is to have SO be Q&A + Documentation. So, this being Meta SO, it's the place for questions/issues with both of those features.

Comment: `is:q -[documentation*]` by active is the new home page

Comment: @JNat Pretty annoying though, as I mentioned.

Comment: Just what I suggested [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328607/why-is-documentation-reputation-counted-as-the-main-reputation)

Comment: It's the first day. I suspect the flood of docs questions will abate somewhat soon. We certainly appreciate everyone's patience in the meantime.

Comment: @hairboat no plan to revert the rep thingy? Or you guys going to stick to that?

Comment: Rep cap has kicked in for new stuff, @Mr.Alien. Recalc for what went over it earlier should occur later.

Comment: @JNat Rep cap is something different, throwing away free rep for copy pasted docs is not what am going to support... Try to discuss it with the team, and re calc and move the rep to doc specific profile and not the main.

Comment: There are even serious delays in the rep and response notifications (for both meta and main-site) today :-( ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I mentioned in [my comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328654/let-documentation-having-its-own-meta-site#comment369858_328654), **Documentation is not going to have a separate Meta from Stack Overflow**. That's because Documentation *is a part of Stack Overflow*. Stack Overflow started off as Q&A, but it does not mean *just* Q&A any more. Stack Overflow means Q&A + Documentation + Jobs — Tim explained this *way* better than I can [on this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310066/1328704) a while back, and I really recommend reading that post.

That being said, Meta Stack Overflow is the place for questions/issues about Stack Overflow as a whole — meaning the Q&A software, the Documentation software, and the Jobs software.

Comment: Well, I'm going to draw that dry straw :-P ...

Comment: Time to quit :)

Comment: [Documentation is part of Stackoverflow](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PO6n0.png).