# Should we have Meta [Documentation] Topics covered in Documentation?

Tags: feature-request, documentation, meta, documentation-topics

Just as asked in the title.

My inspiration comes from that never ending flood of questions tagged [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation) coming up here recently.

Shouldn't we let docs eat all of their *own dog food* rather to cover all of these questions at Meta Stack Overflow? (Note I've been posting a related request very early already: [Let documentation having its own meta site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328654/let-documentation-having-its-own-meta-site), and it was declined).

Is [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation)<sup>beta</sup> already powerful enough to document itself, without feeding noise to Meta Stack Overflow? (could be used as *proof of concept* IMHO).

Is anyone actually willing to make that topic proposal at the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation) beta site? (me probably not)

---

To be absolutely clear (well, what's the meaning of clear in context of quantum physics):
All of the above is meant to blow [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation) away for apparently **not being able** to document itself, this missing the point all over for all the rest as well.

Comment: Well, there is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/documentation/topics).

Comment: @JonEricson LOL Sure, yes. But I prefer asking at MSO mainly before such gets just drowned.

Comment: mm...? http://i.stack.imgur.com/kNcgw.png

Comment: @Braiam Be honest. That doesn't actually fix the problem.

Comment: So what _is_ the problem?

Comment: @JonEricson _"So what is the problem"_ You can read _satire_? It's actually not **my problem** but MSO's. I'm just trying to outsource it, where it actually should go to :P

Comment: Sounds like the problem is "meta is used for its intended purpose after a feature release". I'm not sure we can really fix that. ;)

Comment: I agree with Adam: this week has been downright _exciting_ around here! What do you want? To go back to the daily grind of "I was downvoted and got no comments!" "I got mean comments on my question!" "I was downvoted after I commented on my downvote!" "Why am I blocked from asking questions when I've deleted all my questions so that I can pretend none of them are downvoted?"

Comment: @AdamLear Wasn't [tag:documentation] meant to fix that problem? My point basically is that documentation  doesn't document itself good enough to appear in _beta state_ already. It was dropped prematurely, otherwise this problem would have been solved self contained. I'm looking at [tag:documentation] like looking at _Schrödinger's Cat_ ATM. That's what I'm trying to point out. But explanations make the joke gone, so that's actually bad :( ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I dunno, maybe I'm too close here, but none of this comes across like a joke to me. #TooSoon?

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in a comment, it already exists.

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/documentation/topics

It didn't answer the question I had, and probably won't generally be production quality for quite some time to come, but I applaud the initiative.

Comment: _but I applaud the initiative._ + one for that. As a _tripleee_ should act on quantum physics concerns. :)