# Please tell me what reputation comes from documentation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation, reputation

Honestly -- I really do not like that I get reputation from documentation -- it pads peoples rep and I really do not know what it represents in the grand scheme of things.

## But

Since we are stuck with it anyway, Can there be some way on the reputation page from me to see what rep I got from Docs and which I got from Q&A?

Right now it is all jumbled:

[image]

And you cannot tell what is from where unless you *"click into"* it.

I am proposing some way to have maybe a separate tab so we can delineate rep from Q&A and rep from the Docs.

---

#### Side point:

I know there is not enough freehand circles, but I honestly do not remember how to make them on a Mac -- so If someone wants to add them, go right ahead :-)

---

Related question: [Why is documentation reputation counted as the main reputation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328607/561731)

Comment: Because ... not all reputations are the same?

Comment: @Telkitty Yes, basically.

Comment: @Telkitty reputation from docs is free (you make a small edit, correct or not, and get rep for ever). Reputation from answers takes at least a small amount of effort and has some validation.

Comment: Rep from docs is easy to get now. Just like Q/A rep was easy to get back in the day. Just sayin'... Besides, who cares about rep gain past 20k? It's the <1k rep users approving crap that has me worried more...

Comment: How to draw freehand circles on a Mac: 1) Open Preview 2) Hit cmd-shift-A 3) Select "Sketch" tool 4) Brandish it like a madman 5) Get Meta upvotes 6) ??? 7) Profit

Comment: I certainly hope we are ***not*** *"stuck with it anyway"*. SO officials may still come to their senses.

Comment: This maybe fairest solution: Just put indicator somewhere what % of total rep points I got from Docs (for those who are concerned)

Comment: I'm all for this, and frankly think rep is completely broken now, but it seems like it would be annoying to recalculate rep, what with a common rep-cap.

Comment: Now at-least some-one will definitely cross the reputation of Jon-Skeet by just writing documentations ;). http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga Why is it annoying? They've already done it once and I'm fairly sure they will do it again when the rules have been decided.

Comment: @Ali786 There's still a rep cap in place. It would take someone 12 years to catch Jon with only documentation rep, so perhaps we should all stop the exaggerations? :)

Comment: @DavidG "*seems* like it would be" annoying because I don't know how they implemented it. They have? You mean when they dropped it from 10 to 5?

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga Yes exactly, when they did that and fixed the rep cap, they went through the entire system and recalculated everyone's rep.

Comment: There [is a way](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173633/does-the-preview-app-have-a-freehand-pen-pencil-tool) to draw freehand circles on Mac OS.  I lament that the accepted answer neglected to include them by example.

Comment: What I'd prefer is if it kept track of how much reputation is gained from Documentation in general, alongside how much is gained from _useful_ edits to Documentation.  If you take the time and put in the effort to write an in-depth example, or add useful information/clarification to and/or fix significant error(s) in a pre-existing example, then you earned any reputation gained from it, and it should be marked as "useful Documentation", IMO.  If, on the other hand, you just fix a couple typoes or reorder paragraphs, then you didn't really earn the rep, and it shouldn't be considered useful.

Comment: Is really reputation in a web so important?

Comment: Apparently it is @J_P