# Sudden change in Stack Overflow reputation

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-history, reputation-graph

Recently I've notice a sudden change in my reputation at Stack Overflow. Here is print screen of the graph:

[image: Screenshot of reputation graph]

It seems I've lost a lot of points in one day, but it doesn't shows any reason & also no changes inside Stack Overflow activities. Here is a print screen:

[image: Screenshot of reputation changes from a user profile]

How can that be?

Comment: See [here in the FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history), but it hasn't yet been updated to account for the beast that is Documentation.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your [reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5311928/marina-k?tab=reputation) shows that on August 19 you lost 120 reputation, because [an example which you contributed to](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises/848/image-loading#t=20160819110843133) was removed.

[image]

Comment: Hey, can you explain - how and where you see it? Because I followed the link and it doesn't shows that

Comment: @MarinaK. Change the tab from "graph" to "time".

Comment: @MarinaK. you have to click the entry for a day (Aug 19) to see the details (just in case you or anyone else wasn't aware).

Comment: *sigh* Docs rep should really be separate from SO rep.

Comment: @Zizouz212 related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330323/561731

Comment: I can agree with that sentiment, @Zizouz212 -- one the same note, I can also see the merit of joining the two. I don't think the latter outweighs the former though.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck I think that gaining reputation on Documentation is really a measure of expertise, even moreso than on the main site. Gaining rep on Docs should unlock privileges on Docs, but not the main site. They are two very distinct sites.