# Should off-topic comments be flagged?

Tags: discussion, comments, declined-flags, meta, comment-flags

I posted an answer to the question [Sudden change in Stack Overflow reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333299/3853934). Here's the content of [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333300/3853934):

> Your [reputation
>   history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5311928/marina-k?tab=reputation)
>   shows that on August 19 you lost 120 reputation, because [an example
>   which you contributed
>   to](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises/848/image-loading#t=20160819110843133)
>   was removed.
>
> [image]

Someone posted [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333299/sudden-change-in-stack-overflow-reputation/333300#comment388921_333300) on this answer, with the following content:

> *sigh* Docs rep should really be separate from SO rep.

That might be a good point, but I don't see how it is relevant to the question and the answer. I flagged that comment (and two other comments which were responses to that comment) as "too chatty", but my flags were declined. What is the reason of that?

Comment: On meta the too chatty rule is more relaxed because we hat fun and that comment had 27 upvotes, now 28, which gives an extra reason for a mod to let the comment alone.

Comment: @rene We have _fun_ on meta?? Need to eat more of your (nightshade)  fruits I guess.

Comment: @rene It didn't have that many upvotes in the moment of flagging.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I dismissed those flags. We're a lot more permissive as far as what comments are acceptable on Meta. The whole point of this site is to host discussion about Stack Overflow, which will involve people stating their opinions and sometimes veering a little off topic.

Those comments also weren't entirely unrelated to the discussion there. The question was about confusion due to main Stack Overflow reputation changing suddenly. That sudden change was caused by something changing over on Documentation, and Zizouz212's comment lamented the fact that Documentation reputation and Stack Overflow reputation were tied together.

Given the votes on the comments and the fact that I thought they harmed nothing by being there, I decided not to delete them. Removing someone's comments here could possibly be seen as silencing their opinion, so we have to treat this with a little more care than we would on the main site. I wouldn't worry about a couple of Meta comment flags, since whether or not they are accepted doesn't really hurt or help you here.