# What are the guidelines for comments on meta?

Tags: discussion, comments, meta, deleted-comments

I cannot seem to find any guidelines on when comments on this meta site will be deleted. What are the rough circumstances when a moderator will delete meta comments?

[I did find one post about deleting comments on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333786/1934286)

The gist of it about covers what I'd expect, but there doesn't seem to be any official guidelines. I recently had a pretty normal comment deleted (twice), so I think there should perhaps be official guidelines if that's typical here.

---

I know the traffic on SO is many times larger than other sites, but my impression of other sites' metas is that comments are very rarely deleted. They pretty much have to be abusive before there's any intervention.

Comment: Comments _are_ rarely deleted on meta. That said, maybe insight into why the specific comment was deleted would be more appropriate as everything is evaluated on a case by case basis

Comment: I've had plenty of my comments deleted.  Being critical of SO employees is a good way to get there.  Or chat-rooms, that's an easy dozen users that flag the comment.  Or whatever else you might do to piss-off a significant number of users, having to listen to what you say is not in the bill of rights.

Comment: @Hans Silencing a voice is a very different thing than ignoring it ...

Comment: @fredsbend Hans was mostly referring to auto-deletions by pile-up flags (some flags will auto-delete the content when a threshold of flags has been reached). No moderators are involved in such deletions. _Moderators_ rarely delete comments on meta due to the whole "censoring of unpopular opinions" thing. The reference to being critical of SO employees is something else, I have seen a very large number of comments being critical of SO employees without deletion, so I have no insight on the deletions in that regard

Comment: @TinyGiant I don't think auto-deletion could have done it on my comments I reference, unless the attention to the comment was orchestrated in chat or something weird like that. I may ask separately about that later, but for now, just hoping to see something here in a general sense first.

Comment: There is no general guidelines for comments beyond [Be Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) and that comments should at least be tangentially related to the topic at hand. On popular posts that attract chatty comments, overly chatty comments may sometimes be purged

Comment: @fredsbend We're in a [police state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_state). You and I are branded criminals. _(I enjoyed your long post on that blog. And I upvoted your stuff out of spite.)_

Comment: @ADTC They're going to reverse it. Likely suspend you too.

Comment: @fredsbend to hell with them. I know I contribute good stuff and I'm not a jerk like them, and if they don't want my contribs, then so be it.

Answer (score 16):

To add some context to [Alon Eitan's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355569), here is the first comment you posted:

> "Please answer your question before you ask it." LOL. This community has really degraded since I joined five years ago.

LOL. That is not a constructive comment.

I was not the moderator who deleted this one, but I would have. I probably would have let it slide, erring on the side of not suppressing minority opinions, except that you put something in quotation marks—thus implying it was a quotation of the person whose comment preceded yours—when it absolutely was not anything close to a quotation. Instead, Alon Eitan's preceding comment was:

> I didn't downvote, but if I would downvote that question it would be because it shows lack of research and debugging effort on your behalf (But I didn't downvote, so maybe one of the downvotes can explain their reasoning)

Your misrepresentation of that comment was, quite frankly, both rude and abusive. It has nothing to do with silencing opinions. I have lots of controversial opinions, and have rarely if ever felt that my voice was silenced here. However, we do regularly clean up non-constructive comments.

It is not hard to see how Alon interpreted that as rude, since it was an absolutely disingenuous misrepresentation of what he had said, and since it landed directly in his inbox as a "response" to his comment.

What really upset me, though, was your second comment—the one I deleted in response to a flag:

> "Please answer your question before you ask it." LOL. This community has really degraded since I joined five years ago.

Yes, you read that right. That one says exactly the same thing as the first one did.

It seems one would have gotten the message the first time, after having had the first comment deleted, and *maybe* would have tweaked the phrasing slightly on the second attempt. Alas, no such luck.

So yeah, I *happily* deleted that one in response to a flag, and I seriously contemplated sending you a message about rudeness. I ultimately decided against it, because I figured it was just a moment of weakness and you were venting frustration. We give quite a bit of leeway for that on Meta, and having comments deleted—even as "rude/abusive"—does not inflict any penalties on your account.

I think that answers the more general question here, too. We don't really have "guidelines" for comments on Meta. Moderators are much more lenient here when it comes to comments than we are on the main site. In general, comments on Meta are only deleted because they are truly obsolete or truly offensive/unconstructive.

Comment: I seriously thought my missing first comment was a glitch or something. I'm baffled this got deleted. "Rude and abusive"? You gotta be kidding me! Would it help if I put a winkie face after the quote, since LOL didn't cut it? Perhaps if I sipelled it out literally: "I feel like you're telling me I have to answer my question before I ask it. LOL. This community has really degraded since I joined five years ago." Or is the problem actually the second or third phrase?

Comment: @fredsbend Why not just, *I feel like you're telling me I have to answer my question before I ask it.*? You're no longer making a misrepresentation, just an interpretation, and the rest of it doesn't need to be there.

Comment: I don't know what else I could say that would be any more clear. I'm equally baffled you don't see how the comment was rude. LOL doesn't mean anything close to the same thing as a winkie face. LOL implies you are laughing at the stupidity or absurdity of the quotation; a winkie face *might* imply that you are deliberately misconstruing the comment, or it might imply something else completely inscrutable (tends toward the latter for me). The problem is *all the phrases*. There are at least a hundred ways I could rewrite it to say the same thing in a less rude, more constructive way.

Comment: @BSMP Maybe that's all true. Maybe it's also true that this community doesn't handle that kind of criticism well. The SE sites I've spent a lot of time on don't handle it well either, but I've *never* seen it deleted.

Comment: @Cody Seriously, do you believe somebody could mistake my quote for accuracy rather than satire? It was a reply to a 40 word comment.

Comment: Yes, I mistook it for an attempt at a legitimate paraphrase. It did not strike me as satire. Lots of irony here, by the way. One is the implicit accusation that I might be interested in silencing criticism. That's funny because I am an extremely vocal critic of all sorts of things that are done here. The other is the complaint about comments being deleted, when I am simultaneously being criticized by several others about my refusal to delete comments that they've flagged. @fred

Comment: @Cody Satire is supposed to be legitimate, in a way, just also exaggerated and funny, hence the LOL. I can concede that misinterpreting my comment is a possibility, but I do think that's kind of the attitude here sometimes. They put askers between a rock and a hard place. A catch 22. The final impression is that your question is just plain unwanted. But why delete the comment, instead of replying "that's not what he said"? Nevermind that anyway. My question here was about comment deletion guidelines on meta, not about my deleted comment.

Comment: I understand now how you meant it, and I'm sorry if our deleting it left a bad taste in your mouth. As stated, we try not to do any sort of heavy-handed moderation on Meta. I feel very strongly about preserving this as a place for alternative viewpoints to be exchanged, in part because I am often one of those people who has alternative viewpoints, but mostly just because I fundamentally believe that criticism and self-reflection is how we improve. I sort of see your point here about research effort; you might be interested in [this previous discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592).

Answer (score 0):

It was me who flagged both of your comments, as I got a notification when you posted them.

They were both the same cynical and about how the SO community was deteriorated (That was the word you used) in the past 5 years since you joined.

Flagged both as **rude or abusive** and then a moderator deleted them. Nothing personal against you BTW.

Comment: You can find the next sentence " *I recently had a pretty normal comment deleted* " in the OP post. And apparently the comments could be deleted (checked the history but couldn't find it). It appears that the OP was not aware that his comments were not appropriate.

Comment: I didn't take it personally. Still seems a normal comment to me.

Comment: So criticism of the SO community is not allowed?

Comment: @fredsbend:  Being critical is fine.  Being rude is *not*.

Comment: @Makoto I said: "This community has really degraded since I joined five years ago." Is that actually rude?

Comment: @fredsbend:  Can you defend it as being *constructive* at all, then?  I get that your opinion of the community has dimmed, but you're not really saying anything that we can take action on, nor do we get any guidance on how we're degrading, so we can actually *improve*.  So yeah, I'd consider it rude.

Comment: @Makoto It's a comment not a post. Perhaps details would be forthcoming if the community engaged and replied, instead of just flagged and deleted. Which do you suppose I think is the ruder action?

Comment: @fredsbend:  If you have a specific issue with a specific part of the community, feel encouraged to make a Meta post about it.  Make it a constructive conversation instead of an accusatory one, and you'll likely get somewhere with it.  In the mean time, I'll stop bugging Alon's inbox.

Comment: @Makoto This was on meta. On my own post. Which had no answer, only a single comment.

Comment: This post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355382/may-i-have-some-feedback-on-the-voting-on-my-most-recent-quesion

Comment: Which is now deleted :/