# Show Q & A rep and Documentation rep separately

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation, reputation, profile-page

Would it be possible to show my own reputation earned from Q & A and from Documentation separately in the profile page.

> **Example:**
>
> [image]

Would this be feasible?

Comment: I actually think this is a good idea anyway - but another implication is that we have a careers module, and a high-rep user no longer means that someone has extensive knowledge in a language or framework - just that they made a good edit to some docs about a specific part of the framework.

Comment: @MacroMan Yup, but maybe this can only be viewed by the user himself, so others will only see the combined rep

Comment: @MacroMan rep never proved extensive knowledge of the technologies you work with; it proved that you could provide technical information and explanations that were valuable for others, but that doesn't necessarily mean a deep knowledge of the subject matter. What I think many resent about the rep system for documentation is that (many of us think, me included) documentation rep isn't even particularly correlated with providing value to others; it's just a gold rush to chuck up an arbitrary trivial code snippet without explanation and get hundreds or thousands of rep for it.

Comment: Related: [Please tell me what reputation comes from documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330323/please-tell-me-what-reputation-comes-from-documentation) (for the reputation tab), [Add indicator saying if user has contributed to Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330028/add-indicator-saying-if-user-has-contributed-to-documentation) (a pictorial representation under the user's avatar)

Comment: @MarkAmery Completely agree, but I would bet fair money that a recruiter who knows little to nothing about programming would probably see rep as "ability". Not me though. I see it as unicorn dollars.