# Is there a reputation gain for contributing in Documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation

It is currently being [discussed in the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117558/documentation-public-beta) that there is some reputation (to be awarded on the main site) for contribution in the [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/).

**Is this the case? Why [SO?](https://stackoverflow.com/)**

Comment: "If yes, then it's a bit terrible! It is highly likely that it would degrade the quality of what a beginner would read." - you base this on what exactly?

Comment: I think this would be an example of [Group think](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupthink). Yes, it will obviously encourage more and more contribution but this would not ensure that the quality of posts is maintained.

Comment: `this would not ensure that the quality of posts is maintained.` how, and why? Not that I completely disagree: especially at this stage, maybe there shouldn't be rep gains. But in the long run, it seems silly not to award reputation for good content.

Comment: Why would "no rep incentive" be more likely to ensure maintenance of a quality standard then "some rep incentive"? On the main site gamification has been proved to be a good way of getting people to spend time on activities.

Comment: @Pekka웃  Ok, so for example, assume that after say 4 years, a new user joins. (S)he see that it(editing and contributing stuff) is an easier method to earn reputation than to actually ask/answer questions on the main site. It might lead to unnecessary edits on `Documentation`.

Comment: Well, users starting out on Documentation instead of Q&A wouldn't be a problem at all, IMO. Users making unnecessary edits would certainly be one. But that is a problem that can (and I'm sure, *will*) be tackled by fine-tuning the system. It's not something that invalidates the entire idea of reputation points for Documentation edits.

Comment: @MartinSmith That's a really good question. Actually, the very act of writing a  documentation is boring for some! It would be very nice of the experts of the respective languages/technologies to cross-check the documentation, but again, it may become cumbersome.

Comment: @Oded I was just being skeptical:) I didn't know that [Documentation was going public beta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328405/documentation-has-entered-public-beta). Also, [I'll](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow) [be](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306213/warlords-of-documentation-your-questions-answered) [reading](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319319/documentation-the-update-en-ing) [a lot](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328444/documenting-the-problems-with-documentation) :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, reputation is awarded for contributing to Documentation. This is the case because we want people to contribute to Documentation, and reputation happens to be a great way to encourage people to do that.

It's a little unbalanced right now, but that can be fixed.

Comment: Thank you for answering ^_^

Comment: [Just *a little* unbalanced](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31833655#31833655)

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus Remember that you're looking at about three month's worth of inboolstring's work leading up to this point.

Comment: @Undo: thanks for clearing it up, I thought he earned all of this today.

Comment: @Undo Please see [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328866/dont-give-me-reputation-points-for-making-an-edit-to-a-documentation-topic?cb=1)

Comment: IT is definitely unbalanced right now, and points contributed to documentation should defnitely be separated from those obtained answering questions. It really makes no more sense to conflate the two than to conflate points from answers in meta and in SO. These are different topics. Hence the rewards should be each in its category!!

Comment: @user3743222 Yes, precisely. Please have a look [at this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329459/how-much-reputation-is-given-per-documentation-post-per-day-convert-to-communi?cb=1).