# Will there be a close reason for "Covered in Docs"?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, documentation

Since we started building a ton of examples in Documentation, will there be a close reason in the future when the question is clearly covered in one of the doc examples?

Comment: Or maybe we could close as a duplicate of a doc example

Comment: Before we can even begin talk about closing as documented, we first need to let people search documentation.

Comment: Hehe, that's the closest thing to an "RTFM" close reason - of course I'm all for it :)

Comment: Every time I read "Documentation" here at SO, I understand "Examples" or "Recipes" i.e. specific working sandbox toy solutions catalogued in a meaningfully, practically proven ordered way and that can be indexed into robustly - so I would consider it (if it succeeds) more a positive example answer proxy that can be linked to in a more stable way.

Comment: I thought that this is a good idea - it was point 4 in my answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/330388/61938) :-) (Well, docs as answers rather than close reasons, but potato potahto).

Answer (score 58):

Well, that'd be... *Really* nice, wouldn't it? Pick an example that does exactly what the asker's asking how to do, close, done.

Truth is, it's a bit premature to tell if that's a good idea or not. Nice thing is, we're tracking *links* to docs from answers, so we'll be able to get some reasonable estimates for this on down the road a bit. If nothing else, maybe we can encourage folks to use docs instead of writing the same damn answer every time they see a question. That'd be almost as good, really.

Time will tell...

Comment: So [tag:status-deferred] for now?

Comment: _"maybe we can encourage folks to use docs instead of writing the same damn answer every time they see a question"_ - if that would actually happen, I would be sooo happy.

Comment: "Status INSUFFICIENT DATA FOR MEANINGFUL ANSWER", @NathanOliver

Comment: If we did this, then it might make sense to migrate some canonical answers to documentation too.

Comment: That would mean all our carefully curated content will be moved to or closed by docs.

Comment: Only if folks are idiots about it, @PeeHaa. Why get rid of a good dup-target with tons of inbound links? Plenty of stuff that gets asked a lot *without* having a good canonical though, and lots of... uh, friendly disagreement... as to how canonicals should be created.

Comment: @Shog9 I think that's too meta for a Q&A site.

Comment: Although the idiots part is true we have seen a lot of duplication already as it is while everybody jumps on the free rep.

Comment: Yeah. There'll be some cleanup to do. Growing pains...

Comment: Are you also tracking links to docs from comments?

Comment: I don't believe so, @ajb

Comment: @Shog9. **Re:** "Status INSUFFICIENT DATA FOR MEANINGFUL ANSWER".  Has enough data been accumulated to shed more light on how we should refer to / defer to Documentation when dealing with Q&A?

Comment: Not really, @markE - I'd suggest we revisit this in maybe 6 months, ideally after there's been a public data dump with Docs data.

Comment: @Shog9 Roughly 8 months later, any ETA on that data dump or revisit?

Answer (score -10):

Documentation shouldn't become a substitute / replacement for good quality answers. There are plenty of good questions / Answers that are answered by referencing existing documentation. The answer to the question will explain the context of that documentation in the case the user is asking. (sometimes)

If the question is a bad question, it should be closed for existing reasons. If someone asks a good question and they haven't found / understood / *something* the documentation page, then they should get an answer, that points to the documentation page. This helps in coming searchers in future to understand the context of the question, and the answer that is given, complete with a link to documentation for them to find further details.

Essentially we're suggesting having an RTFM close reason, its just that the manual has moved internally to SO.

(edited /rewritten to clarify)

Comment: So if you ask a bad question then it would be okay?  Anyways isn't this kinda what we do though with dupe closure already?  We don't give the user and exact tailored answer but we give the a answer that when understood and modified to their exact conditions works for them.

Comment: if it is a bad question, we already have plenty of reasons to close it. One of the most frustrating features of MSDN forums (for me) was that you would get links to documentation that didn't even come barely close to answering what you were asking. It was just vaguely in the same ball park. Being able to close a question for the same reason would just be frustrating.

Comment: Why should a fine question be closed? Let's get real here - way more questions should get closed and I have seen almost zero closed questions that shouldn't.

Comment: @juergend I don't think good questions (fine? autocorrect?) should  be closed, I think we have plenty of reasons to close bad questions, I don't think a 'covered in docs' adds anything to SO (and very strongly detracts)

Comment: Absolutely, "I read 'how to filter a list' \[on Docs\](link-to-doc) and I don't understand it because blah blah blah." is not closable as a duplicate. On the other hand "How do I filter a list?" _should be_ closable as a duplicate. The latter is readily transformed into the latter, but until it is it should be, and stay, closed.

Comment: The difference with RTFM is that this points out the exact part of the manual to read. How is closing  as duplicate of a documentation item with a canonical example of the code required worse than closing as duplicate of someone else's question?

Comment: @MartinSmith: "*The difference with RTFM is that this points out the exact part of the manual to read.*" Not only that, our "manual" entries are designed to be fairly standalone.