# What to do with questions on SO which now get documented™?

Tags: support, documentation

For example, the question [Getting WinDbg without the whole SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736250/getting-windbg-without-the-whole-wdk) might (in 4-6 weeks) become answered by the documentation [WinDbg: Installation or Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/windbg/1833/introduction-to-windbg#t=201607220646233771449).

How to proceed in such a case?

- Add an answer to the question, linking to documentation
- Edit the accepted answer, adding a link to documentation
- Add a comment linking to documentation
- Use a special "link to documentation" feature I have not found yet

Comment: related: [Will there be a close reason for “Covered in Docs”?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328658/will-there-be-a-close-reason-for-covered-in-docs)

Comment: Add an answer, just linking to documentation would be a link only answer which was so far frowned upon. The idea was to include the essential points in the answer which on the other hand results in some sort of content duplication.

Comment: @Trilarion: Link only answers were not acceptable since the link could get broken. I guess it can't break for documentation since it's on SO itself.

Comment: @Thomas link rot is not the only reason. The point of an answer is to provide a solution on the very page of the OP. Answering with a link only is just sending me elsewhere and extremely lazy. It does not even attempt to explain anything. It just defers the person. Also, who guarantees that SO will not shut the docs thing down again? It's a public beta.

Comment: @Gordon: regarding the beta, I agree that we should wait until it's released before replacing things that will be deleted. I also agree for the link: we should have an option to inline the documentation like `#INCLUDE [Documentation-Link]` or so.

Comment: @Thomas fwiw, I'd agree to nuking the whole thing.

Comment: @Thomas Link only answers were also not acceptable because the link often did not answer the question directly and there was either too much or not enough information in the link.

Answer (score 1):

The first and second option seem great to me, depending on whether or not the question *is* answered, or if it has an accepted answer. That not only surfaces the documentation, it gives the folks that worked on it a little extra rep.

I would not use comments, because they're pretty ephemeral by nature and not exactly the most visible thing (depending on how many there are).

What *might* be helpful is having documentation picked up above the 'linked' questions in the sidebar, if the system sees unreciprocated links from docs to the question. This would help surface it even if folks forget to edit (albeit in the sidebar), but that's just an idea at this point.