# Quick way to embed documentation example in an answer

Tags: feature-request, documentation, editor, posting

Now that we have documentation, I was thinking it would make answering a lot easier if one was able to directly embed a specific Example from documentation into a post. It would be similar to Stack Snippets. I am imagining a button on the formatting line next to the Snippet button. It would direct the user through choosing a tag, a topic, and then a specific example to embed.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

There's already this nifty dialog for *linking* to examples...

[image: the dialog]

It's triggered by the normal "link" button or keyboard shortcut (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>), but now sports a tab for Documentation on Stack Overflow.

It'd be nice if this offered a way of actually embedding the example inline, but I'd be concerned about folks creating essentially link-only answers if this were *too* easy.

#### See also: [Will there be a close reason for "Covered in Docs"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328658/will-there-be-a-close-reason-for-covered-in-docs)

Comment: If people do give link only answers, that'd be a sign that the close reason should be created. After all, closing a question as duplicate is a link only answer in some sense.

Comment: Yeah, there might be something there

Comment: This must be outdated? CTRL+L in a Stack Overflow answer doesn't give me a dialog like that.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation