# Create an easy way to "promote" code in an answer to a documentation example

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-examples

Obviously there are great code examples to be found in the wild on SO.

Can a mechanism be provided to facilitate creating a Documentation example from them?

Either just a code block, or part or all of an answer?

---

I know... you can edit the answer, copy the content, open Documentation, find a topic, create an example, paste the code...

But I was thinking maybe a pop dialog or similar to make it easier to do, and make the idea more obvious, and therefore be more frequently used.

Maybe an action link that appears near a code block, similar to the way the "edit tags" link appears.

---

#### Edit

My intention was not clear... I did not intend the process to be totally automated. Rather it would open a new doc example with the right name and under the right topic, but the user would still be expected to turn it into a good example , like making it as generic as possible etc (not specific to the question from whence it came etc)

Comment: Cool idea... Probably not gonna happen during the beta, but might be worth cooking up a userscript as a proof of concept.

Comment: I'm not sure we should be doing this, but at least having a specific feature for it will allow the answer's author to be added as a contributor to the Docs example (where copy/pasting will not).

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I was just about to comment about plagiarism... The author should also have a say if that happens.

Comment: @Shog my edit to the question may possibly be relevant.

Comment: @Laurel OK. Good idea. Why not add a attribution and a link to the SO answer in the example then?

Comment: FWIW, I was picturing this as a tool for *authors* - essentially, "this answer is getting really long; break off part into a Docs example?" Maybe with Clippy only being *implied* in the UI though.

Comment: @Bohemian That sounds better. Hopefully that will help inform people how to properly attribute works. Hopefully people won't over use the feature...

Comment: @Shog9 what about having a docs example *embed* within an answer? ie the example renders within the answer, but not statically - the current version is imported at render time (or cached and periodically reflected/updated if the example is edited)

Comment: Yeah, that'd be cool. Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329096/quick-way-to-embed-documentation-example-in-an-answer

Comment: @Laurel *"The author should also have a say if that happens"*  For what possible reason?  Authors have *utterly no say* in anything on SO - all text becomes entirely the property of SO.  Note that authors can't even *delete their own works* if they want to.  It seems unbelievable in the SO commercial milieu that there would be some sort of idea you can't just freely copy and paste QA items, when making Doc. items.

Comment: @JoeBlow I think I mixed up two ideas there. If the feature was to add the OP to the list of Docs authors and credit them rep, it would upset the people trying to avoid participating in Docs, especially if they feel Docs rep is illegitimate.