# Can we get a soft ban from requesting a proposed changed if your proposed revision gets denied so many times?

Tags: feature-request, documentation

For the past two days, I've seen one user repeatedly trying to make the same change in the java arrays section by swapping two paragraphs. It's obvious his intent to just to be recognized as an editor to get rep. I believe if we implement a soft ban or waiting period for a day or few, similar to when you ask a bad question and have to wait a few days to ask another, would solve this problem.

Comment: It would probably be more similar to the _suggested edit_ ban than the question one. The suggested edit one is indeed a temporary ban, based on how many of your edits are accepted versus rejected in a given period of time.

Comment: Maybe those two paragraphs really should switch places? Minor edits to very good posts could be useful, specially on docs, but there's a hostile attitude against minor changes, probably because of rep. Maybe a non-reputable edit would be in place, for the very small changes, like typos?

Comment: @FilipHaglund cause I got a lot of rep. You can take my word, that there was no need for the edit.

Comment: Sure, in this case, but in general?

Comment: Link to the change please?

Comment: There's also been a 1 rep user who has attempted to add the same thing (an entire "topic") at least 4 times. Although in this case, it was rejected because it should have been asked as a question.

Comment: @Javant: So you should be trusted just because you have "a lot of rep"? (You don't, by the way.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I gonna assume you could't tell the sarcasm in my remark..

Comment: @Javant: Indeed, I could not!

Comment: May I remind everyone that people with a lot of rep are officially called "trusted user"s?

Comment: Is it possible to flag edits as "Community Wiki" in order to disavow any rep? That way people could make small constructive edits without all this suspicion being directed at them.

Answer (score 12):

**Would it solve the problem?** Maybe.

The idea of a ban is a good idea in my opinion, although the true answer will only be known if it is tested. However, it really depends on how long the ban is for. If it is for 24 hours, that really isn't long enough to have an effect on the user. If it was for a week, well, the user couldn't add anything else on any other pieces of documentation, some of which *could potentially be helpful*. Perhaps 3 days could work - but it will be up to the site owners to decide that.

**What about reputation?**

If you really think that they are trying to do it for reputation, then personally, I wouldn't be surprised. In fact, there has been [some discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329940/can-we-please-introduce-more-reputation-limits-for-examples-on-documentation) about changing the reputation ratios in documentation.

**In conclusion**

A short ban of 3 days could be helpful if they keep making a similar edit that is rejected by numerous users.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328703/addressing-documentation-repgateapocalypse and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330108/reduce-or-dont-award-reputation-for-docs-upvotes