# Docs rep should promote good edits, not word+code dumps

Tags: discussion, documentation

Looking at [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/126478), I see a truly useless Example getting whipped into shape.

Surely, its author is a "major contributor"? [No](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/5446); instead we have the OP (whose post was good) along with the person whose mess was being cleaned up in the latest edit.

This mess-maker basically dropped random stuff in -- unrelated to the Example and the Topic; formatted inconsistently with what preceded it; creating brand new example data for no good reason -- and so gets votes ever after thanks to how well others cleaned up that mess?

Rewarding net character addition (the current rule is +350 characters?) encourages this very destructive behavior. And by devaluing net removal, the system is telling good contributors that what they're doing is not valued... even though, in this case and every other that I've seen, they're adding far more value than some "major" contributors.

---

Unlike [earlier](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329528/remove-or-overhaul-reputation-in-documentation) posters on [the topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330108/reduce-or-dont-award-reputation-for-docs-upvotes), I don't care if it is a "Rep Gold Mine" or if it cheapens rep earned on Q&A or whatever. My problem is that -- looking at the Docs rep system in isolation -- it is clearly not promoting good edits. This was noted from the outset:

> The biggest flaw I still see is the length based dependence of the reputation gained. This will incentivize bloat, i.e. overly verbose contributions with a low density of information.
>
> This problem will aggravate over time, when it becomes less about building up content but more about improving quality of existing content.
>
> This may seriously impede the success of Documentation!
>
> -- [Trilarion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334599/) on [Documentation Reputation Update Is Live](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334551/documentation-reputation-update-is-live) in September 2016

My opinion is that we'd be better off without the rep system than with what we have now, but I'm looking for a discussion, not a feature request.

Comment: I would rollback instead.

Comment: Well, there's also the problem of the fact that the mess-maker's edit was approved.

Comment: And such careful, painstaking reviews people are making on these edits. I mean, this one was reviewed for a whole *2 seconds* by one person: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/122457?filter-tags=r

Comment: @BradLarson Wrong link? First reviewer was 3:58 on a 3:55 edit, about two minutes. For a second there was afraid you were showing a link of me approving a bad/bloaty edit, which I've surely done.

Comment: @Frank - Oops, appears the review duration column is a moderator-specific display. The review times on that ranged from 2 - 36 seconds, most at the low end. A lot of these are being approved by relatively low-rep accounts who can't access any other review queues. Not exactly getting the best quality reviews on these edits.

Comment: There's a general review problem. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/126476?filter-tags=c%2b%2b) a bad example about a sophisticated C++ template metaprogramming technique, approved by 4 users with a combined C++ score of 0. ::shrug::

Comment: I'll get the shotgun ma...it's ready to be [put out to pasture](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_out_to_pasture).

Comment: Why not limit approvals to badges folks have? For example if they have the PHP badge, or C++ badge etc, which means they are a subject expert on some level? The problem I have with documentation is that you are seeing an edit versus the whole of the documentation, and its really a matter of opinion of what would be considered a useful example or edit. In some regards documentation seems to be too specific but the example could generally be useful. The answer may be to have a very basic example and then an "implementations" tab where users can add their specific flavor of how to use the basics.

Comment: @Shawn I don't follow "you are seeing an edit versus the whole of the documentation"..? Regarding it all being opinion based: in the case I brought up, I think it's pretty unambiguous that an Example about subsetting matrices does not need edits that shows multiple ways to create matrices. Tangentially related stuff can be connected via internal Docs links, treating it like a wiki.

Comment: This is a good, thoughtful analysis of a particular problem with Documentation. But - at risk of being wholly unconstructive - until I'm persuaded that [Documentation has a purpose](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343678/whats-documentation-for) and that there's any way that even *good* contributions can actually get connected to people who will benefit from reading them, I simply don't give a shit. Why does it *matter* whether people are incentivised to throw good technical writing into a burning hole or to throw bad technical writing into a burning hole? Both are a waste.

Comment: @Shawn What you suggest has been asked for and has been declined.  They feel it would be to little people able to review if you need a badge.  Me personally I think at least one reviewer should have to have a badge so it can be reviewed for technical content.

Comment: @MarkAmery I like your post there, but the use-case for Docs is folks landing from google search or Q&A links, so only the last bullet (after you've reached the asyncio Topic) should really matter. If that was better written; had links to related Topics and official docs; and had good google ranking, it could help people. No point making sure people can find it until it's worth looking at (by improving its google ranking), though. Keep bad editors away and at least there's some hope of getting somewhere.

Comment: @MarkAmery I agree with both aspects of your question and the answer. I look at documentation as a canonical reference that goes beyond a skeleton explanation that you would find at say MDN. Truth be told I think the problem is in categorization, as well as perhaps there needs to be an official form that requires several components. Wikipedia solves these problems by flagging pages (which documentation does too) saying that something needs to be improved upon. But I think part of your argument on the problems stem from it being beta, however maybe the biggest change is to just remove rewards.

Comment: (cont.) For example it may be that there is a 50 to 1 word ratio to code, such that people need to be verbose in their answers. Personally I would love to see languages adopted by their owners (Google/Android) here on SO. In that case you would have experts who could see trending examples submitted and give a verbose introduction to it. If none of those are good ideas I am a fan of the documentation because in general I believe more information is better than none in the case that it MAY help, which is better than NO help/resource.