# Should I get reputation for multiple edits in the same documentation topic?

Tags: discussion, documentation, reputation

Suppose I did two changes to a topic in the Documentation project.

If someone upvotes the topic, should I now get +5 reputation (or whatever number is deemed fair in future) for both my changes, or only for one of them?

I believe I only get it for one of my changes (didn't check how it's handled now by the system). But is it right? I have claims both for and against it:

- If I did two useful changes to the same topic, I could have done it as a single change, so I should get my reward once, right?
- However, if I did a useful change, I should still be motivated in some way to continue improving it, right?

Comment: It has been said that Documentation is a rep gold mine. Because of this, I think only the first edit should be rewarded. Otherwise, everyone will rise too quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The way edits work is that the first edit adds your name to the list of editors. Your name can only be listed once per example, so you only get +5 rep for each up vote. I have confirmed this by looking at reputation gains for people who have multiple edits where the example was later up voted.

Some things cannot be voted on (like the Versions section).

That being said, you will still get the +2 reputation for getting an edit approved, but that is awarded once per edit, regardless of how many votes there are. You can also get additional +2's for suggesting edits to the same question or answer, so there's nothing new there.

In general, the story that Documentation is a rep farm is [a bit overblown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/330343/6083675). It does provide a little bit of rep, but it's usually still less than one would get from answering.

Answer (score -1):

> I should still be motivated in some way to continue improving it, right?

Or, going the other way with incentives:

- Make each improvement request dock all editors 50 rep until the requester is satisfied (or 10 approvers overrule them).
- Let editors jointly partake in rep losses for downvotes, say -5 each.

That way, an example can be either a millstone or a gold mine, depending on what the community thinks of its quality.

Comment: Not sure if this is a good idea, but throwing it out there to see what people think. Don't be shy with downvotes -- I'd probably downvote this answer too.