# The forms and quality of Documentation Topics

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics

Much has been said about what "topic" means on Docs.SO. The Powers That Be seem to feel that it is best for users to decide what "topic" means. Now that we're 3 weeks in, I thought it would be good to take a look at a documentation tag and try to see if any patterns emerge. Furthermore, I thought it would be interesting to rate how good these kinds of topics are, relative to one another. That is, to find out which kinds of topics suit Docs.SO best.

Since I know very little about C#, I figured that [Docs.SO's C# tag](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/topics) would be a good place to look. It also has the largest number of topics.

Also, I'm trying to avoid a subjective evaluation of the *quality* of a particular topic or example. That is, I'm not asking whether the examples are good examples, whether they are clear and reasonable. I'm more interested in the different patterns among topics and how they relate to certain systemic issues with the Docs.SO model.

I was able to catalog 4 general species of topics:

- Lists of stuff

  These topics are broad lists of things. What makes this species distinct from others is that the list is based on something quite arbitrary. The most obvious forms of such topics are the "C# <insert version here> Features" topics. What version a particular language feature was introduced in is effectively arbitrary. There are other forms of these broad list topics. "[Keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/26/keywords#t=201608121947461796521)", "[Operators](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/18/operators#t=201608121948279018197)", and the like.
- General language/API features

  This species of topic covers a feature of a language that is broadly applicable to many uses, or some element of an API that is broadly useful within that API's domain. It doesn't really matter *what* you're doing in C#, a working knowledge of [Constructors & finalizers](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/25/constructors-finalizers#t=201608121950134417149) would be of use. [Lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/46/lambda-expressions#t=201608121951400894371), [Naming Conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/2330/naming-conventions#t=201608121952124055266), and similar things represent broad topics that users need regardless of what they're doing.
- Narrow language features and/or specific API classes/methods

  This particular species of topic deals in stuff that has narrow use cases. Even something like [Async-Await](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/48/async-await#t=201608121955596285642), while quite useful (I imagine) is only of particular use if you're doing asynchronous processing. Similarly, how to [format](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/79/string-format#t=201608121956305842253) [strings](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/22/string-interpolation#t=20160812195643147754) is handy to know, but only if you're doing string manipulation. And so forth.
- Tasks/Techniques/Idioms

  This species of topic is the most specific: it focuses on how to do a single, generally well-defined thing. The various ways to [implement a singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/1192/singleton-implementation#t=20160812195824562906), for example. Idiomatic ways of [returning multiple values from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/3908/function-with-multiple-return-values#t=201608121959576182549). In some cases, these techniques have broad applicability. But what makes them distinct from general features is that the topic is about *what* you're trying to do, not *how* you're trying to do it.

So this is our Topic Taxonomy. So, how do we go about judging them? I will use the following general criteria:

- Utility of example voting and ordering. Docs.SO is fairly unique in that it allows elements of documentation to be graded, and will put the highest voted one first. I've found that how useful and meaningful such voting is depends primarily on the kind of topic involved.
- Example count and completeness. First, we need to know which kinds of topics attract lots of examples. More than that, different kinds of topics lend themselves to having a notion of being "complete". That is, is it possible to know if a topic has gotten to the point of fully covering itself.
- Utility of the "Remarks" and "Syntax" section. Different kinds of topics make these sections useful in different ways. [The intent with these sections is to reduce redundancy in examples.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329486/734069) It would be good to see what kind of documentation makes better use of these than others.

The goal is not to offer some kind of numerical grade. It's simply to catalog how well each kind of topic does.

### Lists of stuff

**Utility of example voting and ordering**: Unhelpful.

Each example in such lists exemplifies a specific and *completely separate* aspect of the list. As such, there is no genuine first or last. This means that it is entirely arbitrary which example gets to the top.

Take [Keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/26/keywords#t=201608121947461796521) as an example. The first keyword is `as`. I don't use C#, so it may be that this keyword is frequently used. But somehow, I rather doubt it sees more use than `if`. And that keyword is *way* down in the middle of the list. Indeed, the top 3 keywords are `as`, `volatile`, and `goto`. Three keywords I rather suspect are not frequently used.

Why are they highly voted? Because they were introduced during the *private* beta. By contrast, `if` was added in the public beta, a half-year later.

The ordering of the [Operators](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/18/operators#t=201608121948279018197) topic is rather more reasonable, with the highest voted post being the overloadable ones.

**Example count and completeness**: Most of these topics have huge numbers of examples. However, they also have a well-defined way to measure their coverage of the topic.

These topics are based on arbitrary collections defined by some external metric. Features in a particular version, keywords, etc. Thus, this metric can easily tell us whether we have all of the examples to cover the topic or not.

**Utility of the "Remarks" and "Syntax" section**: Mostly useless.

The remarks are used in the Features pages to specify when a particular version was released. It's used in the Keywords page to provide a full list of keywords, with links to their examples as an ad-hoc Table of Contents.

The Operators page has a very inventive use for Syntax and Parameters. It shows the syntax for defining overloads for the overloadable operators.

### General language/API features

**Utility of example voting and ordering**: Painfully unhelpful.

Each example within these topics is its own entity, describing one aspect of a general system. However, unlike the previous set of topics, these examples often *could* go into an order that is genuinely useful to a reader of a topic. Some examples are simpler and others more complex. Sometimes, they even have to rely on information from one another.

Consider the [Constructors topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/25/constructors-finalizers#t=201608121950134417149). One might reasonably start with the default constructor, then move onto copy constructors, constructor delegation, base class constructors, etc, in that order. That may not be the best order, but for a user browsing a topic, it would probably be a *better* order than the one they currently have, which is arbitrary and based on voting.

**Example count and completeness**: These topics tend to have many examples. Not necessarily "too many", but 6 or more is common. As to how complete one can tell a topic is, it varies.

The Constructors topic represents a focused language feature. However, the documentation for the [Lambdas topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/46/lambda-expressions#t=201608121951400894371) is not really about the feature itself. These examples are mainly of the "here's where you can use them" variety, rather than of the "here's how the syntax works". With the latter, you can see when you have fully covered the syntax. With the former, it's unending. There will always be more places where you could use lambda expressions.

**Utility of the "Remarks" and "Syntax" section**: Not well utilized.

I looked through several C# topics of this classification. I found very few that used the lower sections as anything more than introductory material or for miscellaneous notes.

The only one that stood out was [Nullable types](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/1240/nullable-types#t=2016081221081412484), which managed to use the Syntax field to show off several forms of nullable type declarations.

### Narrow language features and/or specific API classes/methods

**Utility of example voting and ordering**: Somewhat useful.

In the [File and Stream IO](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/4266/file-and-stream-i-o#t=201608131339362150782) topic, voting patterns seem to favor the more useful examples over more special-case concerns. File reading and writing are first, followed by less common tasks like file copying, moving, and deleting. [String Interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/22/string-interpolation#t=20160812195643147754) shows a similar bias towards utility in terms of voting.

**Example count and completeness**: Quite a few examples, but not many of them have "too many". Among the largest was [File and Stream IO](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/4266/file-and-stream-i-o#t=201608131339362150782). As to completeness, it varies from topic to topic.

There is a finite bound to the general things you can do with File IO. [FileSystemWatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/5061/filesystemwatcher#t=20160813135206370898) has only so many uses. By contrast, [Await/Async](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/48/async-await#t=201608121955596285642) has an unbounded number of possible examples. String Interpolation is similarly open-ended.

**Utility of the "Remarks" and "Syntax" section**: More generally useful.

None of the topics I looked at used these sections to deal with information repetition. But when a topic is about a specific piece of the API, they were able to make Syntax actually define the available syntax for the operation.

### Tasks/Techniques/Idioms

First, a note about the C# form of this species of topic. The number of topics of this form is quite small, compared to the others. Also, they tend to be shorter, less used, and much less visible (none of these topics are on the first page of C# topics). So what I document here represents a sampling of a small and seemingly unpopular group.

**Utility of example voting and ordering**: Sometimes very useful.

The [Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/1192/singleton-implementation#t=20160812195824562906) topic represents a case where the voting on individual examples orders them based on the quality of the implementation of the task/technique/idiom is. The [Multiple Return Value](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/3908/function-with-multiple-return-values#t=201608121959576182549) topic is useful in the same way, with the best way of solving the problem voted to the top.

However, we can also see that this breaks down if the topic has not had much attention. Without a decent number of votes, [XML serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/1292/xml-serialisation-and-deserialisation#t=20160813135625095216) can't build a useful ordering of information.

**Example count and completeness**: Again, these examples seem to be somewhat disused, so it's hard to say. But they certainly don't have "too many" examples. As to how complete they can be, it is usually bounded.

There are only so many ways to make a Singleton or return multiple values from a function. So in many cases, task topics are limited in the number of examples they can have.

At the same time, it really depends on what you're documenting. XML serialization with C# is bounded, but only because the language/standard library actually has a solution to that problem. A similar topic in C++ could have dozens of solutions, each involving different libraries and so forth, because the standard itself doesn't offer an answer.

**Utility of the "Remarks" and "Syntax" section**: Mostly unused.

The only topic of this form that made use of Syntax was XML serialization, to document the actual object responsible for it. The others occasionally used the remarks section for the usual introductory material.

### Conclusions

The goal of this taxonomy and analysis is to try to see how topics are being used on Docs.SO, so that we can achieve a useful definition of the term "topic". Hopefully once we have that, we can use it to improve Docs.SO. I'll post my conclusions below, but I invite you to draw your own conclusions or add your own insights into the current uses of topics.

Comment: Noobs will come for #4 (examples and snippets) and experts will come for #3 (specificities and edge cases). I think that #1 and #2 are mostly redundant, non-exhaustive and of poor quality overall.

Comment: @Knu: "*Noobs will come for #4*" I think you underestimate the utility of category 4. Consider the topic of reading an entire file. I imagine that most experts would just use the obvious API function, but some found more efficient ways. That's useful to know for experts.

Comment: My conclusion: The fixed structure of SO Documentation (votes, sections, topics) is in general not very useful for the task of documenting and should be largely abolished in order to build good documentation.

Comment: @Trilarion the thing is that it isn't supposed to "document" as we are used to, but to "show you an example".

Comment: @Braiam If that is all, why not staying with Q&A. Every Q&A shows me an example and I can vote on it and the voting selects the most useful example and all questions are sufficiently focused too. I just ask myself currently: Is there anything more to Documentation that goes beyond the already working Q&A part??

Comment: @Trilarion because in Q&A we expect you to do research, read the documentation and have at least a well structured idea of how things are going to work before we can tell you the answer (mind you that it doesn't necessarily means that your logic will be used). Examples allow you to drop most of that and establish a single general logic of how things are supposed to work independently of the context.

Comment: @Braiam I'm not so convinced. The quality bar for Examples is surely as high as for Answers in the Q&A part. If I make an example I have to do research, read the documentation and have a very well structured idea of how things are going to work. Sure, Examples/Documentation skips the question part, but in a way all Documentation topic titles are questions if you add a "How to" prefix. At least between self answered Q&A and focused topics I hardly see a difference. If anything Q&A is a bit more general because it allows more tags per topic.

Comment: @Trilarion not convinced of what? I know the quality of Examples.SO is higher, and precisely because we don't have to play along with someone else constrains we can write examples The Right Way™. And, if you have to do research to write an example, maybe you shouldn't be the one writing it..

Comment: @Braiam Not convinced that Examples allow one to drop most of the things you mentioned are obligatory for Q&A.

Comment: Even without a question, the Q&A site allows you to make one up and answer it.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thank you so much for your time to outline such a large number of observations in such a thoughtful way.  This was a very interested and thought-provoking read.

Answer (score 20):

It seems to me that most of our problem topics come from the first two categories: lists and large-scale, broadly applicable features of a system. Topics seem to work best when they are about focused concepts.

Given what we've seen here, it seems clear that if we want topics to have a limited number of examples, topics of the form "lists of stuff" have got to go. While they usually have finite sets of examples, they also usually have *very large* finite sets.

The last two categories, specific features and task/idioms/techniques, seem to hold the most promise for achieving the goal of keeping down the number of examples.

The question of voting is also solved by using the more focused topics. What does it mean to vote an example higher than another? That it is more important? That it is more useful? Better quality? How exactly do examples in a topic compete?

Competition among examples makes more sense the more focused a topic is. With specific features of a system, voting patterns tend to indicate which part of that feature is the most useful. With task-based topics, voting patterns indicate what solution to that problem works best.

I think the competition aspect of examples is a good indicator of whether a topic is too broad. If multiple examples within a topic are equally important, then voting makes no sense. But for topics where examples really do have some objective importance can benefit from that.

I think the taxonomy could be redefined as follows, respectively given the above ordering:

- Lists of stuff.
- Explanations of general tools.
- Explanations of tools that do a specific thing.
- How to do a specific thing.

Given that redefinition, it also explains something I noticed subjectively. The less focused a topic is, the more likely it was that the topic would simply be a re-statement of existing documentation.

If you want to find out which features of C# were in any particular version, that is only a Google search away. If you want to know how C# constructors work, how lambdas work, and so forth, MSDN has your back. Yes, it may not be "example focused documentation", but the information *is there*.

And quite frankly, learning to read reference documentation is an *essential tool* in a programmer's belt.

However, if you want to know how to read a whole file in C#, Google leads you to MSDN, followed by a SO question. The MSDN link is adequate, but according to the SO question, it's not the most efficient way to do so. If you want to know how to write a singleton in C#, Google [sends you to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx). But MSDN's article on the subject doesn't talk about Lazy singletons.

If you have a better idea than what MSDN provides... there's nothing you can do about it.

For Docs.SO to achieve its goal of improving documentation, I think having focused topics about doing specific things is the best way to go. We need to forbid large, broad topics and make Docs.SO about how to get things done.

Comment: I like this taxony and agree that the most useful stuff is how best do do task focused things. But I have big  doubts as to whether it can be encouraged/enforced.

Comment: @DavidPostill: I too have those doubts, but mainly because most of the people who have the power to enforce such a thing have generally given up on Docs.SO.

Comment: I find myself agreeing with this, but then you have to wonder what this system offers over Q&A (even assuming it can be achieved as intended). For example, how to read a whole text file in C#. That's a reasonably scoped question that I could ask, and someone could answer. In fact, multiple people could answer and the *best* solution could float to the top, instead of there being one "canonical" solution that the community has to fight over via edits, which just doesn't work out well in practice. (That question has probably *already* been asked, but too lazy to search for it.)

Comment: You can't ask a question about "how to write a singleton in C#", but that's actually a good thing, because there's no one way to write a singleton. You have to narrow it down slightly, explaining what purpose the singleton serves and its desired characteristics. Then you can ask a question about it, and again, people can answer, and the best wins. I can't see how it would be useful to have a "Singletons" topic, with a bunch of different examples of singletons absent a detailed explanation of their differences and why you would prefer to use each one. Which gets into wordy, non-example docs.

Comment: @CodyGray: "*I can't see how it would be useful to have a "Singletons" topic, with a bunch of different examples of singletons absent a detailed explanation of their differences and why you would prefer to use each one.*" I'm not a C# coder, but even I can determine the differences between the various singleton implementations on that page. The point being that a user can read the different implementations and make their own judgments as to their quality. There really aren't that many ways to implement a singleton.

Comment: While I agree with nearly everything, I'm not sure whether the lists of stuff ought to go. At least if the examples there are not over 10 lines and include some references to the most important topics where these are discussed or used, it perhaps may turn out as being an useful type of categorization - not for beginners, but maybe for us editors and people who want to discover new things they didn't know about yet. I'd like to thus ask the question the other way round: Are these lists of stuff _actively harmful_?

Comment: @bwoebi: Pretty much every "list of stuff" topic that I have seen can be found via Google. It already exists with perfectly adequate documentation. And thus, Docs.SO adds nothing to it. If Docs.SO is intended to improve the quality of documentation, then "list of stuff" topics are not helping. Furthermore, "lists of stuff" are very broad topics, thus increasing the confusion on what a topic is supposed to be. Not to mention, with the current example caps, there's no way to adequately have many of these lists.

Comment: Take as example the bitwise operators in the PHP manual http://php.net/operators.bitwise How is the http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/1687/operators/18019/bitwise-operators example superior? It shows a (much better IMO) _real_ example where to use them. Sure, it could be its own topic, I don't disagree. I just think, the operators shall still be categorized in some way. The lists of stuff are currently our cheap way of categorizing this. We should perhaps add proper categories, don't know. But we editors still need a way to find the topics. Currently links from lists of stuff do that…

Comment: @bwoebi: "*I just think, the operators shall still be categorized in some way.*" Why? To what end? That example would be better placed under a topic for how to actually do the particular thing it describes. The fact that it uses bitwise operators to do it is essentially irrelevant.

Comment: True … Not sure then whether we need these lists of stuff. I still don't think they _need_ to go, but they aren't necessary either, I agree on that then.

Comment: @bwoebi: I think a much stronger idea would be to go with something I suggested earlier: [general categorization](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328700/734069). Make examples first-class objects and allow them to exist within multiple topics. Allow each example to be given category "tags", which users could look at and see all examples within a particular category. And allow categories to exist within categories. That way, if you want to see examples of using bitwise operators, you look in the bitwise operator *category*. This allows "topic" to be its own concept.

Comment: "...We need to forbid large, broad topics..." So topics on Documentation have to become more like questions in the Q&A part. I fully agree, but then I see a huge problem of organizing the topics, the meta-structure. At the very least some tagging of topics.

Answer (score 7):

If you look at the problem "reading a text file", you know why the current layout of Documentation fails.

You'll have to start at explaining what a text file *is*. Basically, it is a file containing some bytes, and those bytes happen to encode code points in a given character set. Which characters correspond to those code points depends on the character set that the writer of that file intended.

Then there's multibyte encoding, which some character sets and encodings support. How to read those characters comprised of multiple bytes? By supporting the appropriate encoding to your text file reader.

Alright, so how to detect the encoding of an arbitrary text file? Wow, that's actually a Hard Problem. See the first few Google hits for "C# detect text file encoding site:stackoverflow.com":

- [Get encoding of a file in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710374/get-encoding-of-a-file-in-windows)
- [How to detect the character encoding of a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520184/how-to-detect-the-character-encoding-of-a-text-file)
- [How can I detect the encoding/codepage of a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file)
- [How to determine encoding table of a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255305/how-to-determine-encoding-table-of-a-text-file)
- [Determine TextFile Encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915633/determine-textfile-encoding)
- [Effective way to find any file's Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825390/effective-way-to-find-any-files-encoding)
- [How can I be sure of the file encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018967/how-can-i-be-sure-of-the-file-encoding)

And only some of the answers to those questions address the real problem: **you can't**. You can hope the file starts with a BOM indicating a particular Unicode Transformation Format (UTF) flavor, which means the character set is the Universal Coded Character Set (UCS). But if a text file doesn't start with a BOM, all bets in regard to encoding and character set used are off.

This would be an excellent chapter in the "Reading text files" documentation, namely one of the first chapters. And it wouldn't even be C#-specific, it's platform-agnostic. This problem exists on every platform, regardless of framework and language.

*Then* comes the .NET-specific problem: *"given I know the encoding of a particular text file, how do I properly read the file using that encoding?"*. Alright, *then* you can direct the reader to the `Encoding` class, which you can initialize to a specific encoding using its properties and methods (`Encoding.UTF8`, `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)`).

Now this class can be used to initialize text readers or call utility methods:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(path, encoding))
{
    string textFromFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Or:

```
string textFromFile = File.ReadAllText(path, encoding);
```

Yet there is *one* example that even barely touches this loaded subject, cause of daily occurring questions on Stack Overflow: [.NET - System.IO - Convert text file encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/5395/system-io-file-class/19218/convert-text-file-encoding#t=201608150958006513024). And about the same code exists in [C# - Strings - Convert string to/from another encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/2227/strings#t=201607221053414331058).

All of this information barely begins to even scratch the surface of the problem "reading a text file", and it does belong on Documentation I think. It falls very well into your fourth category, "Tasks".

Yes, MSDN explains how to pass an encoding to a StreamReader. Documentation can explain you when and why to do so, and how to obtain the proper encoding.

Comment: "*You'll have to start at explaining what a text file is.*" No, you don't. Most people who are interested in knowing how to read a file already know what it is. Also, while detecting file encoding is important, it's not important for the task of reading a file. Or rather, that's a *prerequisite*; people more often than not know how their file is stored. A topic on "How to Read an Entire Text File" reading should certainly have examples for different formats, including BOM-based ones. But the details of how to detect a file's format would be a different topic.

Comment: One interesting thing about that is that the "How to Detect a File's Format" would have to be in a completely different Tag, since it's not based on the language in question. Which now brings up the important fact that not every piece of information that needs to be documented is language/API specific and therefore doesn't fit neatly into our arbitrary tag scheme.

Comment: @Nicol I think you're overestimating the average developer, or at least the average .NET developer. _"Why does File.ReadAllText(path) return weird characters?"_ gets asked on at least a weekly basis, ultimately ending in someone being enlightened about how encodings and character sets work. That being said: I think it would be very useful to have some kind of (topic-)overlapping structure that you can link to, so the word "encoding" used in the `File.ReadAlltext()` examples can explain when you need to provide an encoding, what it is and how to detect it.

Comment: @NicolBolas Re the arbitrary tag scheme, there is a [tag:language-agnostic] tag that could hold "Detecting a Text File's Format"; just got to link it to/from all the language-specific pages on "Reading a Text File". As far as what a text file is, that could well go under Remarks, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

The other topic type I'd add here is 'Introductory material'. Most tags seem to have a topic called something along the lines of 'Introduction to...' or 'Getting started'. Since there's quite a lot of confusion about what exactly these topics should include (or even if they should exist at all) my suggestion would be that these introductory topics are treated as a special case and somehow logically separated from the other topics within the tag.

I suggested in [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332328/1622722) on my question about experience level/audience for topics and examples that a 'meta' section for each tag might be useful. From a user experience perspective it's just plain odd that the intro topic wouldn't be the first thing on the topic list or easily navigable to from other topics. For example, if I land on a topic page from a Google search (probably the most likely route?) and I'm unclear on the examples I think it should be easy to get to the introductory topic. This would also help resolve the confusion about what Remarks are for. A lot of background information on tags is contained within the Introductory topic Remarks. That's a mistake in my view - background relating to tags should be higher up the hierarchy.

I'm still on the fence about whether such introductory material fits well with the voting system for examples (in many cases the order you do things in matters) but that's probably a question for another day!