# Is it worth answering question if someone provides a link for a good documentation?

Tags: discussion, answers

Several times I was thinking whether I should answer a question like the
[Some information about ,,addrinfo" in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40344535).

The question is well formed and I know the answer. There is already a comment at this question:

> The getaddrinfo manual page should tell you everything...

The comment is absolutely correct and I hardly write a description better than the referenced manual page. So I guess the reference to a documentation is correct. On the other hand answers to most of developer questions can be easily found in manual pages or other documentation.

I am not asking about the particular question I want to know what to do in general.

Comment: step one: ***look for a duplicate.*** but otherwise, sure, why not. the comment may eventually be deleted.

Comment: "On the other hand answers to most of developer questions can be easily found ..." The downvote button help tip mentions "This question does not show any research effort" as a potential downvote reason. That contradicts your own assessment "The question is well formed" – the OP there did *not* show any research.

Comment: Absolutely downvote poorly researched questions. but poorly researched doesn't make it off-topic. That specific example might be too broad, but that's a different problem than you're asking about.

Comment: I think that Documentation should be treated as any other off-site resource: if a question can be answered by such a resource, add a link, quote some relevant parts, and perhaps explain it in your own words.

Comment: "The question is well formed..." I disagree. There are five questions asked there.

Comment: Related: [Will there be a close reason for “Covered in Docs”?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328658/will-there-be-a-close-reason-for-covered-in-docs)